# How to sort NULL values last using Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, many-to-many, laravel, eloquent

I've got a many-to-many relationship between my employees and the group table. I've created the pivot table, and all is working correctly with that. However, I've got a sortOrder column on my employees' table that I use to determine the order in which they display. An employee with a value of 1 in the sortOrder column should be first, a value of 2 should be second, and so on. (Or backward if sorted descending) The sortOrder column is an integer column that allows null values.

I've set up my group model to sort the employees by the sort column, but I've run into a problem. The null values always are displayed first. I've tried using ISNULL and similar SQL methods in place of the regular "asc" or "desc" used, but I only get an error.

Here's the code in my Group model:

```
class Group extends Eloquent {

public function employees()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("Employee")->orderBy('sortOrder', 'asc');
    }
}
```

And here's what I use in the controller to access my model:

```
$board = Group::find(6)->employees;
```

What's the trick in Laravel to sorting NULL values last?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Laravel does not take into consideration the `ISNULL` method however, you can pass it in as a raw query and still make use of it as it's more efficient than `IF` statements and the results will stay the same if you ever go beyond 1000000 employees (accepted answer), like so:

```
public function employees()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Employee')
                ->orderBy(DB::raw('ISNULL(sortOrder), sortOrder'), 'ASC');
}
```

**Update:**
You can also use the [orderByRaw()](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-methods) method:

```
public function employees()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Employee')
                ->orderByRaw('ISNULL(sortOrder), sortOrder ASC');
}
```

Comment: This is working solution also for not numeric values, like dates.

Comment: This is the least hacky solution IMHO.

Comment: i tried but got mysql error. but fixed by adding ` in both sides of order like this ```'ISNULL(`sortOrder`), `sortOrder` ASC'```

Answer (score 37):

Just add a minus sign to field and change order to DESC.

```
$q->orderBy(\DB::raw('-`sortOrder`'), 'desc');
```

Comment: For laravel 5.1: 
$q->orderBy(\DB::raw('-sortOrder'), 'desc');

Comment: For Laravel 5.4: $q->orderByRaw("-start_date",'DESC')

Comment: And for Laravel 5.6: `$query->orderByRaw('-start_date DESC')` (note the single string instead of second parameter).

Comment: previous comment is wrong, should be `$query->orderByRaw('-\`start_date\` DESC')`

Answer (score 14):

In Laravel 5.2 or higher just call `orderByRaw`. You even able to sort through aggregated value rather than a column. In the following example `max_st` can be `null` if there is no submodels.

```
Model::where('act', '2')
    ->leftJoin('submodels', 'model.id', '=', 'submodels.model_id')
    ->select('models.*', DB::raw('MAX(submodels.st) as max_st')),
    ->orderByRaw('max_st DESC NULLS LAST');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public function employees()
{
    return $this
        ->hasMany('Employee')
        ->select(['*', DB::raw('IF(`sortOrder` IS NOT NULL, `sortOrder`, 1000000) `sortOrder`')])
        ->orderBy('sortOrder', 'asc');
}
```

**Explanation:**
The IF statement solves the issue here. If NULL value is found, some big number is assigned to sortOrder instead. If found not NULL value, real value is used.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly! I did not know that Fluent chain methods could be used in Eloquent.

Comment: Could you tell me the importance of the brackets in the select? I'm having an odd problem with them. I have two development computers, and one of them has no problems with the brackets, the other one throws a FatalErrorException. I took them out, it works now on both computers, and my query result doesn't seem to have changed.

Comment: Brackets passed to `select()` methods is nothing but new syntax for an Array.

You experience the problem because this feature is new, comes with PHP 5.4. One of your computers run 5.4, the other doesn't.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php or http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: This looks like a bad practice.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this problem recently using Laravel 5.6, where junkystu answer was perfect for me. However our testing framework uses sqlite, so tests were constantly returning a 500 error.

This is what we came up with, which should be slightly more agnostic of a DB driver.

**Ascending**

```
$query->orderBy(DB::raw('column_to_sort IS NULL, column_to_sort'), 'asc');
```

**Descending**

```
$query->orderBy(DB::raw('column_to_sort IS NOT NULL, column_to_sort'), 'desc');
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of relying on an arbitrary large number you can also do:

```
public function employees()
{
    return $this
        ->hasMany('Employee')
        ->select(['*', DB::raw('sortOrder IS NULL AS sortOrderNull')])
        ->orderBy('sortOrderNull')
        ->orderBy('sortOrder');
}
```

It has an added benefit of being supported by SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

More elegantly you can do as below for better results

1. This will order latest to oldest and null to the last.

   ```
    ->orderByRaw("CASE WHEN column_to_order IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC")
    ->orderBy('column_to_order', 'DESC')
   ```
2. This will arrange null records first and then oldest to latest.

```
   ->orderByRaw("CASE WHEN column_to_order IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC")
   ->orderBy('column_to_order', 'ASC')
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for PostgreSQL

For numeric types:

```
DB::table('t')
    ->select(['id', 'val'])
    ->orderBy(DB::raw("coalesce(val, 0)"), 'desc')
```

For text types:

```
orderBy(DB::raw("coalesce(val, '')"), 'desc')
```

The trick is to replace `NULL` values in the sorting column to zero (or empty string) so that it could be sorted as an ordinary integer (or text) value.

Answer (score 0):

**For Nested Relationship**

Nowhere did I find the solution to do the same thing for ordering in a nested relationship. Had to improvise and this is what I came up with:

```php
// Sorting order
$order = 'asc'

// Order Products by $product->store->manager?->name
Product::orderByRaw(
    "(". 
        Manager::select('name')
            ->whereHas('store', function (Builder $q) {
                $q->whereColumn('id', 'products.store_id');
            })
            ->toSql() 
    .") $order NULLS LAST"
);
```

**EDIT** 
OK, I found the query above to be slow, so I rewrote it like this:

```php
$query = Product::query()
    ->leftJoin('stores', 'stores.id', 'products.store_id')
    ->leftJoin('managers', 'managers.id', 'stores.manager_id')
    ->orderByRaw("managers.name $order NULLS LAST");
```

Joins worked 3 times faster than subqueries. But be aware that you'll need to add table prefixes (such as `'products.title'`) to all your further Eloquent calls on this `$query`.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone else needs sortBy using null last for Laravel collection can use this trick,

```php
collect([
    ['order' => null],
    ['order' => 1],
    ['order' => 44],
    ['order' => 4],
    ['order' => null],
    ['order' => 2],
])
    ->sortBy('order')
    ->sortBy(fn($item, $key) => $item['order'] == null);
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will sort null values last:

```
$posts = Post::orderByRaw('ISNULL(`rank`), `rank` ASC')->get();
```

Answer (score -3):

```
->orderBy('sortOrder', 'is', 'null')->orderBy('sortOrder', 'asc')
```

Seems to work.

Comment: Actually, that creates a query containing `order by sortOrder DESC, sortOrder ASC` which does not add NULL values last.

Comment: @junkystu: How did you verify that? I haven't managed to get SQL logging working yet. I'm using Eloquent 5.0 btw.

Comment: use the [debug bar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), it's very nice and even lets you see queries which are ran via ajax among other useful stuff