# Laravel order by date, null-dates always at the end

Tags: mysql, laravel, sorting, date, eloquent

I have to sort orders on my date field `send_date`, but NULL send_dates always on the end.

I have tried this, but this isn't working:

```
Order::orderBy(\DB::raw('ISNULL(send_date), send_date'), 'asc')
->orderBy('send_date', 'desc')
```

How can I sort on send_date, with NULL dates **always** on the end?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644072/how-to-sort-null-values-last-using-eloquent-in-laravel?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Make sure in DB you have `null` not empty value `''` or spaces

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I've read that solution, but it isn't working because I have no order column, but only a date column

Answer (score 1):

Just use the -minus sign beforet the Column name.

```
Order::orderByRaw("-start_date",'DESC');
```

It will order Sort the null values at the end.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
Order::orderBy(\DB::raw("COALESCE(d, '9999-12-31')", 'ASC');
```

This works because if the date is NULL it's considered to be `9999-12-31` which according to [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) is the largest possible date

Note: This only works if you sort ASC but if you sort DESC NULLs are at the end anyway.

[Check the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/952214/8)

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work, because when I filter DESC, the nullable dates have to be also on the end

Comment: If you sort by DESC the nulls go to the end anyway.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/952214/9 the nullable doesn't go to the end...

Comment: There's no magic value that will send NULLs always at the end regardless of sort direction. You can use this code when sorting `ASC` and `orderBy(d, 'DESC')` when sorting by `DESC`.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/952214/13 will work in both cases but as you can see it's ridiculously complicated and cannot be done using eloquent at all (it can be done using the query builder though)

Comment: Is it possible to create a new "order_column"; in mysql: if (send_date = null order_column = 1) ?

Comment: Here's the problem. If you `ORDER BY ... DESC` what you will get is **the reverse** of what you get if you `ORDER BY ... ASC` there's no magic value that always ends up in the bottom when doing both ASC and DESC ordering as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

```
Order::orderBy("start_date",'DESC');
```

i think it will help

Comment: No it doesn't work, because: sometimes I have to order my column on send_date asc, and sometimes send_date desc, but ALWAYS the nullable send_date have to be on the end...