# Flatten nested relationship sorted by parent then child - possible with eloquent alone?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

Is this possible using eloquent alone:

```
// build doc tree
public function tree()
{
    $docs = app(config('lap.model.doc'))->with(['children.parent', 'children' => function ($query) {
        return $query->orderBy('order');
    }])->whereNull('parent_id')->orderBy('order')->get()->toArray();

    $docs_array = [];

    foreach ($docs as $doc)
    {
        $docs_array[] = array_except($doc, 'children');

        if ($doc['children']) {
            foreach ($doc['children'] as $child) {
                $docs_array[] = $child;
            }
        }
    }

    return $docs_array;
}
```

Just curious because despite this working the way I want it to, I'm wondering if there is a better solution that might already exist within the framework capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this can be used in SQL:

```
select t.*
from t
order by coalesce(t.parent_id, t.id), `order`
;
```

i.e. The `coalesce` function uses id when there is no parent_id. This "clusters" the familiy of parent and children together and then rows within the family can make use of the "order" column.

Whilst I'm inexpert at Laravel I believe [orderByRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-methods) may be used, like so:

```
orderByRaw('coalesce(parent_id, id), `order`')
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29732171/2067753)

If using a `coalesce` function is a problem, this alternative can be used in SQL:

```
select t.*
from t
order by case when t.parent_id IS NULL THEN t.id else t.parent_id end, t.`order`
;
```

and that `case expression` could be converted into an `IF` for use by Laravel I suspect.