# Using two different orderBy logic based on a database field (null/not null)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I am trying to `orderBy()` my query based on if a field is NULL or not.

So, if `minute` field is null, I want to orderBy `id`; otherwise I want to use couple of different set of orderBy.

This shows the "minute not NULL" scenario:

```
public function events() {
   return $this->hasMany(Event::class)
        ->orderBy('minute', 'desc')
        ->orderByRaw('type = ? desc', 'period')
        ->orderByDesc('external_event_id')
}
```

What I want to achieve is something like this pseudo code:

```
public function events() {
   return $this->hasMany(Event::class)
        ->when('minute is NULL', function($q) {
            $q->orderByDesc('id');
        })
        ->when('minute is NOT NULL', function($q) {
            $q->orderBy('minute', 'desc')
              ->orderByRaw('type = ? desc', 'period')
              ->orderByDesc('external_event_id');
        });
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this using Laravel query builder?

Comment: Doesn't seem logical, the minute field is a column of events table right? And it's possible that different rows/records may have different values or some can have null values as well. Ordering is done on entire collection of result rows. Imagine that even if ordering could be changed based on column value - ordering would change multiple times in a set of say 100 rows. So that's not logical to implement

Comment: if my answer worked out perfectly let me know  becaue i have not tested

Comment: @Donkarnash hmm, I see your point, but it's a little different for me. Let's say my model is called "Bus". For some Bus events, I know all the minute fields are null. For others the minute information exists. So my idea makes sense in this case, no?

Comment: In that case I think the answer by @Abilogos below is the closest that you can get with the desired results. It is basically bifurcating the query into two getting all records with minute as null and ordering it by id then another query to get all records where minute is not null and ordering it by a different set of orderings and then merging the results.

Comment: Yeah, @Abilogos answer makes sense but unfortunately `unionAll()` messes up the ordering. I also tried `union()` but ordering gets lost again.

Comment: You can execute the individual queries and then concat the resulting collections docs:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-concat

Comment: @senty Have posted an answer with a hackish workaround. Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

A dirty hack which can get close to what you desire

Define two different relations for events on the model

```php
public function eventsWithNullMinute()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Event::class)
        ->whereNull('minute')
        ->orderByDesc('id');
}

public function eventsWithNonNullMinute()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Event::class)
        ->whereNotNull('minute')
        ->orderBy('minute', 'desc')
        ->orderByRaw('type = ? desc', 'period')
        ->orderByDesc('external_event_id');
}
```

And define a method on the model to get all events merged under events key

```php
public function events()
{
    return static::with(['eventsWithNullMinute', 'eventsWithNonNullMinute'])
        ->where('id', $this->id)
        ->get()
        ->map(function($record){
            $events = collect([]);
            if($record->eventsWithNullMinute->count()) {
                $events->push($record->eventsWithNullMinute);
                unset($record->eventsWithNullMinute);
            }

            if($record->eventsWithNonNullMinute->count()) {
                $events->push($record->eventsWithNonNullMinute);
                unset($record->eventsWithNonNullMinute);
            }

            $record->events = $events;

            return $record;
        })->pluck('events');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, again would work but it's pretty dirty indeed. I'll sleep on it and re-think.

Answer (score -1):

query builder has whereNull and whereNotNull function
you can build each query and union them like:

```
public function events() {
   $q1 =  $this->hasMany(Event::class)
        ->whereNull('minute')->orderByDesc('id')->get();
        
   $q2 =   $this->hasMany(Event::class)
        ->whereNotNull('minute')
         ->orderBy('minute', 'desc')
         ->orderByRaw('type = ? desc', 'period')
          ->orderByDesc('external_event_id')->get();

    //collection union
    return $q1->union($q2);
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. Although it makes sense, `->unionAll();` messes up the ordering. If I try `return $q1` or `return $q2` individually, it works though. Any other suggestion to replace `unionAll()` ?

Comment: yes, you right ordering is none sense if there are two different rules whenever you specify which one is prioritize than other rules set. for example first set has higher priority.

Comment: i suggest to first `->get()` the first , then `->get()` the other, then union collections, then return them all

Comment: Again, would work but it's more ideal to do it in query level rather than doing 2 separate DB transactions and sorting in collection level. Using `get()` twice will mess up the relationship too :/

Comment: yes. but if you want to use one query it can be achievable with **STORE PROCEDURE** i guess.  i dont think, with query builder we can go further

Comment: Check this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17644303/4705339

Comment: but you cannot make a constant like a million to your query since you want different ordering rule